# Are there additional Puranas besides the 18 Mahapuranas and 18 Upapuranas?

Tags: puranas, upapuranas, mahapuranas

I read about something called Agneya Puranam that is said to glorify the Kaveri river.  Are there others?

Comment: Yes there are. Vishnudharmottara Purana is a very good example.

Comment: @অনু - Pretty sure the Brihaddharma Purana counts the Vishnudharmottara Purana as an Upapurana. [link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Brihad_dharma_Purana/VtRKAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

One concrete example is the *[Periya Puranam](https://shaivam.org/devotees/periyapuranam-of-sekkizhar-english-translation/#gsc.tab=0)*, compiled by Sekkizhar, that discusses the 63 Nayanars.

A few others are the Saraswati Purana, the [Kubera Purana](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kuber-purana-study-with-text-uan778/) (written by a Jain but about Hindu deities), the Vasuki Purana which is 500 slokas long, and the [Atma Purana](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.368580).

Then there are the various *Sthala Puranas*, which talk not just about gods, but also about temples and regions. One example is the [Sthala Purana of the Meenakshi Amman temple](https://www.templedairy.in/sthala-purana-and-history-of-meenakshi-amman-temple), which talks about Amman and Indra. There are many other Sthala Puranas, though.

The problem is that many of the minor Puranas have been elevated to Upapurana status even if they were not described as such in scripture. This makes it difficult to find good examples.